# Add to cart is not clickable under My account

Tags: magento-1.9

we are displaying **Product name** & **Add to cart** button in Custom tab under My Account . we wanted to add the product to cart once we click on "Add to cart", but button is not clickable, once if we click on button , its not adding product to cart.

```
<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>

<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {

    echo $product->getName().' <br>';
?>

<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)">
<span><span>
<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>
</span></span>
</button>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

</div>
<hr style='display:inline-block; width:100%;'>
<?php 

}
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below code

```
<form action="<?php echo  Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($product);?>" method="post">     
<div class="add-to-cart-buttons">

<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" >
    <span><span>
    <?php echo $buttonTitle ?>
    </span></span>
</button>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: updated code, but now only first product name is displaying and no `Add to cart` buttons displaying as here : http://prnt.sc/eklgw7

Comment: please check full code : http://pastebin.com/heYFAqaS

Comment: @BabyinMagento updated my code I replace `$product` instead of `$_product` in form action

Comment: oh sorry, now it worked like a charm , Thanks for your continous support......

Comment: @BabyinMagento You are always Welcome :)